# Is it possible to align a TextView's baseline with the bottom of the parent layout?

Tags: textview, android-linearlayout, parent, android-relativelayout, baseline

I want to align the *baseline* of a `TextView` with the bottom of the parent layout (`LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`). Is this possible and, if so, how is it done?

Comment: Have you tried align to parent bottom option? I think it's in relative layout

Comment: Yes, but that aligns the bottom of the text---not the baseline.